# Clojure looping based on user input

Tags: clojure

In Clojure I want to create a function that would continually ask the user for an option, execute some code depending on the option, and then quit when the user’s option is “q”.

I am comfortable will all of the various Clojure forms that work with sequences, and I could certainly finagle a Java-like solution to the above, but I cannot figure out how to do this in a “clojuresque” manner.

Thanks,

Jeffrey S

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should do the job:

```
(defn main-loop []
  (case (read-line)
     "q" nil
     "a" (do (println "got a command!") (recur))
     "b" (do (println "got b command!") (recur))
     (do (println "got invalid command!") (recur))))
```